# What is the needed configuration for OAuth 2 authorization with upstream JWT authentication?

Tags: apiconnect

I would like to design a micro-services architecture with IBM connect where the outside clients need to pass a Bearer access token in an Authorization header (OAuth 2) and the gateway will pass a stored JWT (generated and stored during authorize call) with the authorized user's claims to the internal APIs.

Is there such a built-in configuration?

(For reference, WSO2 provides this exact behavior: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT)

Answer (score 1):

There is not such built in feature in IBM API Connect.
A possible implementation for the scenario that you mention, in IBM API Connect, could be:

- An OAuth Provider API that contains the authorization and token endpoints of an OAuth flow (IBM API Connect has a built-in OAuth server) [Implement an OAuth API Provider](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/tapim_sec_api_config_scheme_oauth_endpoint.html)
- The API that acts as a proxy of the backend microservice, secured by the OAuth provider API created before (so that way, access tokens are required to send requests to this API). In this API, implement a jwt-generate policy (which is a built-in policy in IBM API Connect) to generate JWT tokens. [jwt-generate built-in policy](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMNED_5.0.0/com.ibm.apic.toolkit.doc/rapim_ref_ootb_policyjwtgen.html)

In this implementation you can add custom information to the access tokens generated by the OAuth provider API (such as the logged in user in the application, device id....), and use those values as claims when generating the JWT (oauth.resource-owner, client-id of the consumer application sending the requests....)